# Why is my web view fail delegate not working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

.h

```
IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blabla.com"]]];
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webViewfail didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if([webViewfail isEqual:webview]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Failed"
                                                        message:@"Check your Internet connection before refreshing."
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

I do not know what I did wrong, I tried making it appear but setting off internet connection. Any tips or suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Have you set the delegate of the webview to `self`?

Comment: And just in case - is IBOutlet connected to the object in XIB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have hooked up the delegate in interface builder (if that is what you are using). You can do this by selecting the web view, and drag (while holding control) to the view controller / file's owner, and then select delegate (which pops up when you release the mouse).

Or you can hook up your delegate in code in your viewDidLoad method like so:

```
[webView setDelegate:self]
```

Make sure your view controller conforms to the UIWebViewDelegate protocol by adding  in your .h

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

- Make sure the object containing the quoted method is indeed the web view's `delegate`.
- Give the web view's url request a really short `timeoutInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this also:

In your ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

And in ViewController.m below [super viewDidLoad] add :

```
self.webView.Delegate = self;
```